# React component with dynamically created function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that includes an input element. When the value of the input changes the handler function is supposed to validate the input and act accordingly. The actual validator is dynamically created (via `new Function(code)`) with the actual code passed as a string prop to the element. The validation code never changes for a given component.

Right now I am doing the function construction in the actual onChange handler which seems unnecessary. It does not belong in state either. I would like to create the function once, store it somewhere and use it on demand. My question is, where should it be stored? Should I make it an attribute of the actual component object? The `statics` object seems also reasonable, but can one pass properties dynamically (like the code string above) and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomputing the validator inside the onchange is not that bad from a reproducibility point of view. It only affects performance and if that is an issue one possibility would be to use the caching mechanism of your choice:

```
handleOnChange: function(){
    if(this.cachedValidatorString !== this.props.validatorString){
        this.cachedValidatorString = this.props.validatorString;
        this.cachedValidator = new Function(...);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Another, perhaps cleaner, approach would be to update the validatorFunction field inside the render method. That is the earliest you can update it and it guarantees that it will always correspond to your current props.

```
render: function(){
   this.validatorFunction = new Function(this.props.validatorString);

   return <input onChange={...} />;
}
```

---

As for the other possibilities you mentioned:

I agree that this.state is not the best place to put the validator function because in general you want to avoid putting things that can be computed from the props in the state. See [props in getInitialState as an anti pattern](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html)

Finally, I don't think statics would make much sense here. Static properties are shared by all instances of your class but the validator functions need to be different for each instance of the component.